# Proving $ \lim_{x \to 0^{+}} 4^{\frac{1}{x}} = \infty $

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I want to prove that $ \lim_{x \to 0^{+}} 4^{\frac{1}{x}} = \infty $, because I can't isolate $ x $ without flipping the  $ \gt $ sign.

Here is my proof so far:

Given $ M > 0 $, Choose $ \delta = $

Suppose $ 0 \lt x - 0 \lt \delta $.

Check:

$$ 4^{\frac{1}{x}} \gt M $$

$$ \frac{1}{x} \gt \log_4\left(M\right) $$

But now, if I want to isolate the $ x $, I have to flip the inequality sign. What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

You **want** to flip the inequality sign. You want to find some $\delta$ such that, if $0<x<\delta$, then $4^{\frac1x} > M$.

Comment: Thank you, didn't realize that